# CSR1000v image in Openstack as a VM

Tags: cisco, kvm-virtualization, openstack

I have an esxi host. Under that I have created a Ubuntu 14.04 machine running Openstack(devstack single node)Juno release. I am trying to spin CSR1000v image as a VM inside Openstack. I followed the official Cisco docs and still am not able to do it.

The VM succeeds spinning and getting created in Openstack dashboard but in vnc-console it is stuck in boot and doesn't go further. The same image is running perfectly under virtualbox or other appliance.

My Ubuntu has 16gb ram and 8cpu allocated from esxi.

Does it require any drivers? If so how do I provide it via Openstack?

**localrc**

```
> ADMIN_PASSWORD=password MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
> RABBIT_PASSWORD=password SERVICE_PASSWORD=password
> SERVICE_TOKEN=password LOGFILE=/opt/stack/logs/stack.sh.log
> VERBOSE=True LOG_COLOR=True SCREEN_LOGDIR=/opt/stack/logs OFFLINE=True
> RECLONE=no disable_service n-net enable_service q-svc q-agt q-dhcp
> q-l3 q-meta q-metering neutron Q_PLUGIN=ml2 ENABLE_TENANT_VLANS=True
> ML2_VLAN_RANGES=default:800:900
> Q_ML2_PLUGIN_MECHANISM_DRIVERS=openvswitch
> Q_ML2_TENANT_NETWORK_TYPE=vlan PHYSICAL_NETWORK=default
> OVS_PHYSICAL_BRIDGE=br-ex disable_service heat h-api h-api-cfn
> h-api-cw h-eng
```

Comment: Can you give me following details. Which flavor are you using to spawn CSR1000v?
Whats the image version?

Comment: Flavor has 4gb ram, 0 disk, 4cpu..(Tried even with disk and larger config too)...

CSR image is "csr1000v-universalk9.03.13.00a.S.154-3.S0a-ext" in iso..(Converted it to qcow2 and with container as raw)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems working fine post Kilo release and newly downloaded images in qcow2 format.
Flavor which I'm using 2CPU, 4GB RAM, 0 diskspace